# REST_framework Attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I got this error when attempting to get a value for the field `scrumgoal_set` on the serializer `ScrumUserSerializer`:

> AttributeError at /api/scrumusers/

The serializer field might be named incorrectly and might not match any attribute or key on the `ScrumUser` instance.
The original exception text was:

> 'ScrumUser' object has no attribute 'scrumgoal_set'.

**serializer.py**

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','groups','password',]

class ScrumGoalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ScrumyGoals
        fields = ['goal_id','goal_name','goal_status']


class ScrumUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    scrumgoal_set = ScrumGoalSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = ScrumUser
            fields = ['nickname', 'id','scrumgoal_set']

class ScrumProjectRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # user = ScrumUserSerializer()
    # scrumgoal_set = ScrumGoalSerializer(many=True)

     class Meta:
        model = ScrumProjectRole
        fields = ('role', 'user', 'id')
```

Comment: can you show struct of `ScrumUser`